# HTML Horizontal Ordered Lists with Numbering

Tags: html, css, html-lists, horizontallist

I'm using an ordered list in order to get numbering, which works perfectly fine when the list is vertical. However, once I make it horizontal, the numbering disappears.

The display attribute in the li CSS seems to be the culprit.

CSS and HTML:

```css
#QuickSteps {
  width:723px;
  height:75px;
  border:solid 2px #b9c7d9;
  background-color:#e5ecf2;
}

#QuickSteps h2{
  padding-top:2px;
  padding-left:7px;
}

#QuickSteps ol{
  color:#003366;
}

#QuickSteps li {
  display:inline;
}

#QuickSteps li.selected{
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="QuickSteps">
  <h2>5 Quick Steps</h2>
  <ol>
    <li class="selected">Account Info ></li>
    <li>About Me ></li>
    <li>Preferences ></li>
    <li>Habits ></li>
    <li>Your Avatar</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Taming Lists: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/taminglists/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of displaying them inline, you could float them

```
#QuickSteps li {
  float:left;
  margin-left:50px;
}
```

Good luck...